# How can I use an ASP.NET MembershipProvider to carry over users' session data stored in cookies set by ColdFusion?

Tags: asp.net, coldfusion, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I'm working on adding a new webapp to an existing website. I've been directed to write the webapp in ASP.NET. The existing website is written in ColdFusion. For the most part, the ASP.NET webapp is completely stand-alone, but it needs to interact with the ColdFusion code in one important way - if somebody logs in to the ColdFusion site, we don't want them to have to log in again when visiting an ASP.NET page.

When someone logs in to the ColdFusion site, their username is stored in a cookie, along with a login token that can be looked up in our database. My .NET is a little rusty, so I'm having trouble visualizing how the ASP.NET code should use this data. I've already written a simple MembershipProvider that can be used to log in/out out the ASP.NET app using the data in our existing database tables, which are shared with the ColdFusion code.

What I'd like to know is - how can I make sure the ASP.NET app detects the cookies set by the ColdFusion app (I imagine they'd be sent to the ASP.NET pages, since everything is hosted on one domain), and automatically logs the user in using the MembershipProvider and Forms Authentication, using the credentials supplied in the cookie? I'm thinking that putting some kind of cookie check and log in function in the Global.asax file, set to run every page load for every page... but that seems kind of clunky. Also, do people still use the Global.asax file anyway? I had thought there was a more modern method.... Also, how can I manually log someone in using Forms Authentication and a custom membership provider? Currently my code allows the user to log in using the provided login control, but I'm not sure how to log the user in without them having to do anything.

Thanks in advance for any help. Looking over the MembershipProvider tutorials and the MSDN documentation it seems to me like the answer should be staring me in the face, but for some reason I just can't see it. Maybe not enough coffee....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("the username goes here",false);
```

[Reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/981346.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a CF developer ususally, but we had to do some integration with a .NET application recently and the way we approached it was to keep the CF and .NET sessions separate but *ensure that login happened on both* so when the user moved from one to the other they were still logged in.

So is there perhaps a way for you to hit your ASP.NET application with a request to login a user when you login using the CF application? Perhaps you could have an iframe on the page that you can load when the CF login is complete that holds a login service for the .NET app?

This way you would not need to worry about one app server reading the other app server's cookies, instead there would be two sets of cookies, one for ASP and one for CF.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I really need to get the ASP.NET application reading the cookies set by CF. It shouldn't be too hard... we're setting the cookies manually. I'm just not sure where in the ASP.NET code this should be done, nor how to manually log a user in in such a way that the built-in ASP.NET login functionality will recognize it. I don't want to add another IFRAME or other request to the CF login process. With all the 3rd party apps we're using, it's already a convoluted spaghetti process as it is.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach it, is I would have a specific page that acts as a liaison between the CF and .NET layer.  That page would implement your business layer and just check to see if the Cookie is there, if so read it in, do the lookup and login the user or whatever business logic that needs to be done.  How would you accomplish the login/authentication, well that’s all based on your login/authentication code.

The only link I can offer is the basic of cookies in ASP.net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495(v=vs.71).aspx

Edit: found another link that might be helpful.
http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/network/cookies-csharp.aspx

Comment: My question's probably too vague, I'll have to think about how I can improve it. But I already know how to access the value of the cookies in ASP.NET, and look up the user credentials and verify that they're logged in in the database. The step I'm missing is how to make the built-in ASP.NET authentication system recognized them as logged in based on that data.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for:
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("the username goes here",false);

http://forums.asp.net/t/981346.aspx

Comment: I think that is indeed what I was looking for. Who knew it was so simple? Thanks! If you'd like to submit that comment as it's own answer, I'll mark it as the "Accepted" one.